# Can't find mod_authz_svn.so while restarting apache2

Tags: linux, svn, apache2

I tried to install and setup a svn server using apache2,
I followed instructions on internet but while i tried to restart apache2 it shows the following error:

apache2: Syntax error on line 204 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_svn.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so into server: libsvn_repos-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.

i checked the path but the file do exist,im not sure what is happening.
need some help thanks~

Comment: Webserver question, not a programming question.

Comment: @Raoul: Gray area; questions about programming tools (svn, here) are on topic.  He might get a better response on [sf], however.

Comment: @Will he's talking about apache modules, regardless of it being an SVN module, this is a apache setup/configuration issue. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your pathes, it looks like you are playing debian or ubuntu config. if I remember well, this module *mod_authz_svn.so* is available with *libapache2-svn*, so you need first to *apt-get* this module as root, and then to enable it (being in the directory /etc/apache2, *a2enmod my_module*) and reload your apache config (or restart apache).

The other way around is to load the module as a DSO. Then it's a different process.

Comment: Thanks, i guess it's version problem since after i reinstall subversion using apt-get it was solved.i used the version wget from offical.Not knowing why it causes errors.